# Let $A,B$ and $U$ be sets so that $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq U$. Prove that $A\subseteq B$ iff $(U\setminus B)\subseteq(U\setminus A)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ and $U$ be sets so that $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq U$. Prove that $A\subseteq B$ iff $(U\setminus B)\subseteq(U\setminus A)$.

The forward implication is easy to prove but i got stuck at the backward implication, i.e. $(U\setminus B)\subseteq(U\setminus A)\Rightarrow A\subseteq B$. Can someone help me out with it? Thank you.

Comment: Note this difference: $$ U\backslash B \quad \text{versus} \quad A\setminus B $$ The latter has the spacing appropriate to a binary operation symbol.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $C=U\setminus B$ and $D=U\setminus A$. The hypothesis that $U\setminus B\subseteq U\setminus A$ can then be written $C\subseteq D$. Now apply the forward direction to $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply the forward implication to $A'=U\setminus B$ and $B'=U\setminus A$.

Answer (score 1):

well, as others have pointed out:

You've proven $A \subset B \implies U/B \subset U/A$ so

let $C = U/B$ and $D = U/A$ and you have

$C \subset D \implies U/D = U/(U/A) = A \cap U = A \subset U/C = U/(U/B) = B\cap U = B$.

But if you want to do it directly:

$U/B \subset U/A$.

Let $a \in A$ (so $a \in U$).  Then $a \not \in U/A$.  If $a \in U/B$ then $a \in U/A$ which would be a contradiction.  So $a \not \in U/B$.  So $a \in B$ (as $a \in U$).

So $A \subset B$.

Or here is a third way:

Let $a \in A$ but $a \not \in B$.  So $a \in A \implies a \in U$ and $a \not \in B \implies a \in U/B \implies a \in U/A$.  But $a \in A$ so that's a contradiction.  So $a \in A \implies a \in B$.

So $A \subset B$.

Comment: It may be worth adding to the direct proof that "if $a\in B$" simply leads to a vacuous truth, as desired (just as when you say something along the lines of "if $a\in\varnothing$) so it is only necessary to consider what happens when $a\in A$. *Side note:* You may want to typeset the set difference $U/B$ as it is conventionally typeset using the `\setminus` command; that is, `$U\setminus B$` produces $U\setminus B$, as desired.

Comment: It took me while to understand your comment.  That's cute.  I'll add that as a 4th method.

Comment: Wait.  I *don't* undestand your comment.  b in B implies ... what?

Comment: I'm not saying anything about "$b$" in anything...I was assuming your $a\in A$ was simply taken as an arbitrary element like $x\in A$ or anything else in $A$. Looking at it right now, it is probably unnecessary to consider $a\in B$ seeing as that $a\in U\setminus B$ really means "$a\in U$ and $a\not\in B$" (so considering $a\in B$ is rather a waste of ink or characters if that makes sense). But the comment about `\setminus` remains the same! `;-)`

Comment: I briefly included setminus to show idioticly that b in B implies b in A and therefore idioticly I concluded A subset B.  Then I realized that was idiotic and I quickly deleted it.  But while it was up the setminus sign looked really nice.